# Convert a pandas dataframe to tab separated list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Words':['actually','he','came','from','home','and','played'], 
        'Col2':['2','0','0','0','1','0','3']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image: DataFrame looks like below]

I write this dataframe into the drive using below command:

```
np.savetxt('/folder/file.txt', data.values,fmt='%s', delimiter='\t')
```

And the next script reads it with below line of code:

```
data = load_file('/folder/file.txt')
```

Below is load_file function to read a text file.

```
def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    return data
```

The **data** will be a tab separated list.

```
print(data)
```

gives me the following output:

```
['actually\t2\n', 'he\t0\n', 'came\t0\n', 'from\t0\n', 'home\t1\n', 'and\t0\n', 'played\t3\n']
```

I dont want to write the file to drive and then read it for processing. Instead I want to convert the dataframe to a tab separated list and process directly. How can I achieve this?
I checked for existing answers, but most just convert list to dataframe and not other way around.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is possible use `data = load_file(data.to_csv(sep='\t'))` ?

Comment: use pandas pd.to_csv(data,sep='\t',index=None)

Comment: `data.to_csv(header=None, index=False, sep='\t').split('\n')` ??

Comment: Python lists don't have separators, though comma is used in the display of a list.  You can make a string with tab and newline separators.  What kind of processing are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.to_csv()`

```
df_list = data.to_csv(header=None, index=False, sep='\t').split('\n')
```

---

**df_list:**

```
['actually\t2',
 'he\t0',
 'came\t0',
 'from\t0',
 'home\t1',
 'and\t0',
 'played\t3'
]
```

---

```
v = df.to_csv(header=None, index=False, sep='\t').rstrip().replace('\n', '\n\\n').split('\\n')
```

---

**df_list:**

```
['actually\t2\n',
 'he\t0\n',
 'came\t0\n',
 'from\t0\n',
 'home\t1\n',
 'and\t0\n',
 'played\t3\n'
]
```

Comment: thanks @pygirl... exactly what I needed :)

Comment: I get the last element as '' , and had to remove it. Not sure you faced the same , but atleast its not visible in the print you have given above

Comment: actually I removed it manually from the output.   Yes I faced the same thing. Because in the last row I have added \\n. This should be avoided for the last value. You can create a loop to filter out the empty string

Comment: Ah... now that I see, Comma at last was indeed my mistake. But despite removing, I got empty element in the end. Something like this. ['actually\t2\r',
 'he\t0\r',
 'came\t0\r',
 'from\t0\r',
 'home\t1\r',
 'and\t0\r',
 'played\t3\r',
 '']

Comment: Sorry. I was in hurry. Correction it's because of the last row containing `\n` One way of solving this is to use regex or you can filter it out using a loop I willupdate my answer :)

Comment: @Varunkadekar: I have updated my answer :) the string has `\n` in the end which can be removed easily by using `rstrip()`

Comment: thanks... I had excluded final element in next step, but this does the trick in one line. kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this achieves the same result without writing to the drive:

```
df_list = list(data.apply(lambda row: row['Words'] + '\t' + row['Col2'] + '\n', axis=1))
```

Comment: @Varunkadekar: Use of apply should be avoided :) just for info. Because they make the performance slow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: thanks @Pygirl, really appreciate pointers you re throwing here. I was under the impression that apply was better than for loop... atleast in R

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data.apply("\t".join, axis=1).tolist()
```

Comment: thanks Lambda... this works too. Just that I needed '\n' in the end for my next set of processing.

Comment: You can use `data.apply(lambda x: "\t".join(x)+"\n", axis=1).tolist()`